# Matrix that maps points to $ax + by +cz = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Give a $3 \times 3$ matrix that maps all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the plane $ax + by + cz = 0$ and does not move the points on that plane.

I would like some help setting up this problem please.

Comment: Do you know about projections?

Answer (score 1):

We just need a matrix that projects points onto the given plane. We can choose any projection direction we like, so we may as well choose one that makes the algebra simple.

Not all of $a$, $b$, $c$ can be zero, so let's assume that $c \ne 0$. Then the equation of the plane can be written as 
$$
z = -\frac{a}{c}x - \frac{b}{c}y
$$
We're going to project parallel to the $z$-axis, so the projection mapping is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ -\frac{a}{c}x - \frac{b}{c}y\end{bmatrix}
$$
In matrix notation, this is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\frac{a}{c} & -\frac{b}{c} & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$$
The other answers are more complex because they are projecting in a direction that's normal to the given plane. As I said, there's no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $u = \frac{(a,b,c)^T}{\Vert(a,b,c)^T\Vert_2}$ (assuming $(a,b,c) \neq (0,0,0)$, else, $A = I_{3\times 3}$ will do the trick)
Then your plane is $P = \{ x\in \mathbb R^n : u^T x = 0 \}$ so you want to find $A$ such that
$$u^T A x = 0 \qquad \forall x\in \mathbb R^n$$
And so
$$u^T A = (0,0, \ldots, 0)$$
With the additional condition
$$Ax = x \Leftrightarrow u^Tx = 0$$

---

One solution is, if you find a basis of $P$ and let $B$ be the matrix of basis vectors ($B \in \mathbb R^{3\times 2}$) then
$$A = BB^T$$
will do the trick:
Since $u$ is orthogonal to $P$ and thus orthogonal to all basis vectors of $P$,
$$u^T A = u^T B B^T = \binom00 B^T = (0,0,0)$$
And for $x\in P$, $B^T x$ will be the coordinates of $x$ in the basis $B$, so $BB^T x = x$ if $u^T x = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding this. We have not gone over this in class yet. Is there another method to solve this problem?

Comment: You can manually calculate the projection of an arbitrary vector onto the plane if you have a basis for $P$. The resulting Matrix from those calculations will be the one from my second part.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=(a,b,c)^T$.  Then the projection of any vector $p$ on the plane is 
$$p-\frac{\langle p,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v.$$
Now plug in the basis vectors for $p$ to get the corresponding matrix. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}-\frac{a}{\|v\|^2}\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{a^2}{\|v\|^2}\\-\frac{ab}{\|v\|^2}\\ -\frac{ac}{\|v\|^2}\end{pmatrix}$$
is the first column of the matrix.